# use different package repository in emacs

Tags: emacs, package

I have a `.emacs` file in which I use `package-install` to automatically install needed packages from a repository at initialization. Up to now, I was using the `http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/` repository, which I got from an online tutorial. At some point, I tried to install the `auctex` package and got an error message which told me the package was not available under that repository. I checked and it is true. I found out the the `auctex` package [is available](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/auctex.html) under the GNU repository: `http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/` instead.

What I tried to do is the following: add a second package repository (GNU ELPA in this case) to my `.emacs` file from which `package-install` can feed if it needs to install packages not available under the first repository (MELPA).

I am not an expert (in fact, I am a pure beginner) in Elisp and I browsed various threads to find a solution. Here is my actual code:

```
(package-initialize)

(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '(("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")
               ("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")) t)

(package-refresh-contents)

(dolist (package '(use-package))
  (unless (package-installed-p package)
           (package-install package)))

(use-package paredit :ensure t)

(dolist (package '(auctex         ; <-- Not available under MELPA!
                   auto-complete
                   auto-complete-c-headers
                   magit
                   sr-speedbar
                   yasnippet
                   ))

  (unless (package-installed-p package)
    (package-install package))
     (require package))
```

With this code in my `.emacs` file, when I boot emacs up, my configurations are ignored. I get this error message: `error: Required feature 'auctex' was not provided`.

How can I modify my code to see the `auctex` package from GNU ELPA?

For your information, I use Ubuntu 16.04 with GNU Emacs 24.5.1.

---

**EDIT:** Just to add a few words on what Stefan proposed: there were several problems with my code and splitting my `add-to-list 'package-archives ...)` in two calls did not seem, to work (although it is the right thing to do, of course). This was due to my `(require package`) line was trying to do: `(require auctex)` at some point. See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/737835/cannot-run-auctex-on-emacs) to see why that is a problem.

I read on the fact that `(require 'package-name)` is not needed after package installation. [This post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22717/what-does-require-package-mean-for-emacs-and-how-does-it-differ-from-load-fil) explains why. removing this line made sure that `auctex` was loaded correctly, because it was automatically loaded.

From then on, everything worked fine, no more errors or warnings. I then tried to remove my lines:

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
```

and `auctex` package was still loaded correctly.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this: `(dolist (package '(use-package))...)`? That iterates over the list whose sole element is the symbol `use-package` - one iteration only, binding variable `package` to symbol `use-package`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '(("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")
               ("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")) t)
```

doesn't add 2 entries to the list: `add-to-list` only adds a single element to a list.  In this case it will add the element `(("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") ("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))` which is not a valid element.

You'd want

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
```

But note that the second `add-to-list` should be redundant because `package-archives` by default contains `("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")` already.

One more thing: you should not need to `require` those packages after installing them (like you do on the last line of your code), because the packages should come with enough autoloads to make such `require` unneeded (and harmful in the sense that it will slowdown your startup).